# Aggregating pixels of raster dataset using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, aggregation

*I am fairly new to working with raster data in ArcMap. *

I have a raster dataset like in the picture I have uploaded, and you can assume that each individual pixel of the raster has a value which is given in red. What I want to do is aggregate the pixel cells up to the resolution that I want such that I can add the values associated with the individual pixels. In the picture, the original 4x4 raster would be aggregated up into a 2x2 raster, however what I am not sure about is how you could tell ArcMap to add together the cells that you want to have been added.

One possible solution I am thinking of (but haven't had an opportunity to try) is to generate a 2x2 fishnet over the area and try to aggregate the pixels that are contained within the fishnet. I am not sure if there is a simpler way to go about this though.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried? https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/aggregate.htm

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the output that you are after here, there are two approaches that you can take. The first is to aggregate to a different resolution representing the size of your cell groups. [Aggregation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-aggregate-works.htm) will take a group of cells, apply a statistic and then return the value of the statistic to the new resolution.

The second approach would be to keep the same cell resolution but assign all of the cells in the aggregation the same value. This is called [block statistics](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-block-statistics-works.htm).

Both of these approaches are available in the `Spatial Analyst Toolbox` across all versions of Esri software (ArcMap, ArcGIS Pro).